# dataframe KeyError, although it exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the data

```
rows = [
    {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3},
    {'x': 2, 'y': 2, 'z': 3},
]
```

if I try constructing a dataframe like this

```
frame = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, index='x')
```

it works fine. However, this

```
frame = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, index='x', columns=['y', 'z'])
```

(which I would expect to be equivalent) fails with the weird error: `KeyError: 'x'`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `x` in you columns. Eg:

```
rows = [{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}]
frame = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, index='x')
display(frame)
    y   z
x       
1   2   3
2   2   3
frame = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, index='x', columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
display(frame)
    y   z
x       
1   2   3
2   2   3
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `x` to your `columns`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, index='x', columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

Comment: hey whatif the dictionary inside the list are of different key, value pairs, say for instance   rows = [
    {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3},
    {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
]

Comment: That depends on your desired output. Which output do you want?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd

rows = [
    {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3},
    {'x': 2, 'y': 2, 'z': 3},
]

frame = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, index='x', columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
print(frame)
```

**Output:**

```
   y  z
x      
1  2  3
2  2  3
```

Answer (score 3):

`columns` is applied as a filter **before** your `index` argument is processed. Therefore, you see `KeyError` as Pandas cannot find `x` after filtering for `['y', 'z']`. One solution is to `reindex` after reading data into a dataframe:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, index='x').reindex(columns=['y', 'z'])
```

Alternatively, you can specify all fields, including your index:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, index='x', columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

This has the benefit of not reading in unwanted fields and filtering as a subsequent step.

Comment: hey whatif the dictionary inside the list are of different key, value pairs, say for instance rows = [ {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, ]

Comment: @iamklaus, Not clear what you want. Please ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide what you've already tried.