# How to change datetime format and access dictionary in list?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of dict as below

```
result = [{'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 20)}, {'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 21)}, {'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 22)}]
```

I want to access every element on the list and transform the format.

My Expected Out

```
result = ['2019-1-20', '2019-1-21', '2019-1-22']
```

Comment: check this out too...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421806/dataframe-keyerror-although-it-exists

Comment: If you are sure what are you trying to do, you can try : `[j for i in result for j in i.values()]`

Answer (score 1):

You need something like

```py
mylist = []
for res in result:
    mylist.append(res['start_date'])
```

This will 'get' the dates from the `start_date` dictionary key in `datetime` format, so you can keep using them for `datetime`-like functions. If you want the result in a string, you can replace the last line in this example with

```py
mylist.append(res['start_date'].isoformat())
# >>> print(mylist)
# ['2019-01-20', '2019-01-21', '2019-01-22']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of where the build-in [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function OR [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) can be used with great effect.

```
import datetime 
result = [{'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 20)}, {'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 21)}, {'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 22)}]

# Map function
res = map(lambda d: str(d['start_date']), result)
print(res)

# List-comprehension
res = [ str(d['start_date']) for d in result ]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
result = [{'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 20)}, {'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 21)}, {'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 22)}]
result_list = [str(i.get("start_date")) for i in result]
```